# How many VPS do I need for my website?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, hosting, vps

I made a website which aims at simulating a trading market. There are a list of prices and corresponding volumes that people want to purchase. Users can purchase at any price any time. My website retrieves the prices and volumes from my database every 2 seconds (I have to update the user's browser frequently to allow them to see the current market). Users' database INSERT query can be sent any time if they purchase.

I used ajax to post or get data from my database (sometimes nested ajax calls). So, every 2 seconds, each user will send or retrieve data by using more than 20 database queries (in order to show a users the current prices and volumes). Also, I may have 200 users at a time.

I was not using VPS before, and I got banned because of using too much CPU resources on my host. Now, I've purchased VPS*2 from a hosting servers. I have:

CPU Speed: 2000 Mhz

Memory: 2048 MB

Disk Space: 20000 MB

Bandwidth: 2000 GB

Connection: 40 Mb/s

Dedicated IP's 2 IP's

Is this enough for my 200 users?
Also, which VPS OS is suitable for me?

Thank you.

Comment: StackOverflow is about programming. This question is about server configuration. It should be posted at serverfault.com.

Comment: your code is more of an issue than the hardware; but i have seen bad code 'fixed' by throwing more hardware it it.

Comment: If, as @Dagon suggests, your code is more of an issue, you could make this question appropriate for SO by posting your code and explaining what you're trying to accomplish with it. As posted, however, the question is about hardware resources, and does belong at serverfault.com.

Comment: thank you all! sorry about posting on the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your VPS host? see the conditions..

Anyway..
1) Make sure that you're not using too many database connections

2) You might be interested in implement [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)
 (suitable for you webapp, Real-time/low delay update with low resources consumption..

3) Make sure your PHP along with your queries are well written... no loop or other CPU consumption code is running... (you might use bash command / top /ps) to check what system is consumming too much.. (Database, php/webserver...) Consider to do [stress test](http://loaduiweb.org/)

I personally like lunacloud.com